# Extracting zip files from a large binary file

Tags: python, zip, gzip

I am dealing with a somewhat large binary file (717M). This binary file contains a set (unknown number!) of complete zip files.

I would like to extract all of those zip files (no need to explitly decompress them). I am able to find the offset (start point) of each chunks thanks to the magic number ('PK') but I fail to find a way to compute the length for each chunk (eg. to carve those zip file out of the large binary file).

Reading some documentation (http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/ZIP), gives me the impression it is easy to parse a zip file since it contains the `compressed size` of each compressed file.

Is there a way for me to do that in C or Python without reinventing the wheel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some standard ways to handle [zip files in python](https://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/) for example but as far as i know (not that i'm an expert) you first need to supply the actual file somehow. I suggest looking at the [zip file format specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

You should be able to find the other information you need based on the relative position to the magic number. If I'm not mistaken the CRC-32 is the magic number, so jumping forward 4 bytes will get you to the compressed size, and another 8 bytes should get you the file name.

- local file header signature     4 bytes  (0x04034b50)
- version needed to extract       2 bytes
- general purpose bit flag        2 bytes
- compression method              2 bytes
- last mod file time              2 bytes
- last mod file date              2 bytes
- crc-32                          4 bytes
- compressed size                 4 bytes
- uncompressed size               4 bytes
- file name length                2 bytes
- extra field length              2 bytes
- file name (variable size)
- extra field (variable size)

Hope that helps a little bit at least :)

Answer (score 2):

A zip entry is permitted to not contain the compressed size in the local header. There is a flag bit to have a descriptor with the compressed size, uncompressed size, and CRC follow the compressed data.

It would be more reliable to search for end-of-central-directory headers, use that to find the central directories, and use that to find the local headers and entries. This will require attention to detail, very carefully reading the [PKWare appnote](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) that describes the zip format. You will need to handle the Zip64 format as well, which has additional headers and fields.

It is possible a zip entry to be stored, i.e. copied verbatim into that location in the zip file, and it is possible for that entry to itself be a zip file. So make sure that you handle the case of embedded zip files, extracting only the outermost zip files.